# Calculate sum with OR condition on two filters using different tables in DAX

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, dax

I am currently using SSAS and I am struggling with a DAX expression.

I would like to calculate a sum with with filters such as

Table_1.col_A = value_1 OR Table_2.col_B = value_2

I know I can use something like

CALCULATE(SUM(Table_1.col_A);FILTER(Table_1;Table_1.col_A=value_1);FILTER(Table_2;Table_2.col_B= value_2))

IF it is with an AND condition and not an OR. I've tried with and OR() function without success. Is there a way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your tables are joined to each other (which they should be) then you can simply achieve this with one FILTER statement and the double pipes (||):

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table_1.col_A);FILTER(Table_1;Table_1.col_A=value_1 || Table_2.col_B= value_2)))
```

Comment: I tried what you proposed but I got a error :
 "A single value for column 'col_B' in table 'Table_2' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying aggregation such as min, max..." . 
So instead I tried to import co_B into Table_1 with RELATED(Table_2.Col_B) and I used  :
CALCULATE(SUM(Table_1.col_A);FILTER(Table_1;Table_1.col_A=value_1 || Table_1.col_B= value_2)))